# How to populate custom field dropdown with values from DB

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field

I trying to create a new custom field, which will have a select field with menu items from certain menu type, I got stuck at populating this select field with values from database.

You can see the code [here](https://github.com/esedic/listmenus/blob/2b0ad43e139954a653e5284568542090bbd4266b/plg_listmenus/fields/listmenus.php#L42).

Also I need to access these 3 object properties (id, title, link) on frontend, so the goal is to have in table #__fields_values in `value` column record like this:

`{"id":"115","title":"Article","link":"index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1"}`

I got to this point:

Articles-Edit-Joomla-Administration.png

If I print DB query correct values are returned:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 101 
        [title] => Home 
        [link] => index.php?option=com_content&view=featured ) 

   [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 115 
        [title] => Article 
        [link] => index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1 ) 
)
```

But I don't know, how to get this in the select field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that you already tried `return $db->loadObjectList();` and you aren't able to access and convert the data to html option tags?  As an aside, I recommend using `quote("mainmenu")` for sql portability /consistency.

Comment: The link to your script now seems to be broken -- this is why we ask that all question details be written statically on the page.